# Is there a way to query this deeply in the Firebase REST API?

Tags: firebase

I have the data below. I'd like to query it for all users that have "c" – (true or otherwise).

```
repos/users.json?orderBy=???
```

Can I pull this off w/ the REST API?

```
{
  "repos": {
    "my_repo": {
      "tags": {
        "a": true,
        "b": true,
        "c": true,
        "d": true
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "kevin": {
        "a": true,
        "c": true
      },
      "bob": {
        "b": true,
        "c": true
      },
      "alice": {
        "a": true,
        "d": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query from "users" for the values.

```
ref = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/repos/user/").orderByChild("c").equ‌​alsTo("true");
```

The equalsTo is only quoted in my example, depending on how you set it in your data.  If it is a string, you need the quotes, if not, then adjust to match your dataset.

See [Firebase Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/)